# Arranging a sorted list in staggered order

Tags: c#, sortedlist

I have a sorted list which I want to stagger the output of for another part of my project but can't figure it out the output should look like:
[image]

Here is what I have so far (This was made with https://dotnetfiddle.net/) for testing

```
public static void Main()
{   
    List<ColumnArrangment> listVersion = new List<ColumnArrangment>();
    listVersion.Add(new ColumnArrangment { Name ="Questions", Priority = 2, Amount = 2});
    listVersion.Add(new ColumnArrangment { Name ="Parts", Priority = 1, Amount = 2});
    listVersion.Add(new ColumnArrangment { Name ="CodeLetters", Priority = 4, Amount = 2});
    listVersion.Add(new ColumnArrangment { Name ="Answers", Priority = 3, Amount = 2});
    // Order
    List<ColumnArrangment> SortedList = listVersion.OrderBy(o=>o.Priority).ToList();
    foreach(var obj in SortedList.ToList())
    {
        int sortedIndex = SortedList.FindIndex(i => i.Name.Equals(obj.Name));
        for(var a = SortedList.ElementAt(sortedIndex).Amount; a > 0; a--)
        {
            if(SortedList.ElementAt(sortedIndex).Amount > 0) {
                SortedList.ElementAt(sortedIndex).Amount -= 1;
                Console.WriteLine(obj.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
public class ColumnArrangment
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Priority { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }

    public ColumnArrangment()
    { }

    public ColumnArrangment(ColumnArrangment ca)
    {
        Name = ca.Name;
        Priority = ca.Priority;
        Amount = ca.Amount;
    }
}
```

The help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: What is stagger output? What output do you get with this code? What output do expect? Can you share some example?

Comment: @Chetan I mentioned it in the question, but to clarify I want to have multiple of the same object in the list then output 1 set (Parts, Questions, Answers, CodeLetters) and repeat.

Comment: OK so u want to print out each set (Priority 1-4)  based on the Amount property ? What should happen when Priority 1 has Amount 2 and Priority 3 has Amount 5? Or is that not relevant ?

Comment: @jeb In that case it would just tack them onto the end so for your example (Priority1, Priority 3, Priority1, Priority 3, Priority 3, Priority 3, Priority 3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the list is already ordered by priority you can simply print the item and reduce its Amount as long as there are any ColumnArrangement that have Amount.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
        List<ColumnArrangement> listVersion = new List<ColumnArrangement>();
        listVersion.Add(new ColumnArrangement { Name = "Questions", Priority = 2, Amount = 2 });
        listVersion.Add(new ColumnArrangement { Name = "Parts", Priority = 1, Amount = 2 });
        listVersion.Add(new ColumnArrangement { Name = "CodeLetters", Priority = 4, Amount = 2 });
        listVersion.Add(new ColumnArrangement { Name = "Answers", Priority = 3, Amount = 2 });
        listVersion.Add(new ColumnArrangement { Name = "Test", Priority = 5, Amount = 4 });

        listVersion = listVersion.OrderBy(x => x.Priority).ToList();
        while (listVersion.Any(x => x.Amount > 0))
        {
            foreach (var item in listVersion)
            {
                if (item.Amount > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
                    item.Amount--;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

prints:

```
Parts
Questions
Answers
CodeLetters
Test
Parts
Questions
Answers
CodeLetters
Test
Test
Test
```